# How to randomly return the index of one of the maximum elements in a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, max

My program counts the number of times 3 different values appear and stores them in a list like this one `classes = [class1,class2,class3]`

**I want to return the index of the biggest value, but these values will often be duplicates. If that is the case, I want to return an index chosen at random between the biggest values.**

For example, if I have `classes = [5,2,5]`, I want to output either 0 or 2.
If I have `classes = [1,1,1]`, 0,1 and 2 are fine.
Finally, if I have `classes = [1,10,1]`, I want to output 1.

So far I have pieced together this from other questions, but it's not behaving the way I want and I dont understand why.

```
classes = [class1,class2,class3]
dupes = [n for n, x in enumerate(classes) if x in classes[:n]]
class_prediction = dupes[random.randint(0,len(dupes))] + 1
```

(The +1 at the end is to return the actual class label instead of the index.)

Comment: To clarify, you really need to choose one of them at random? (It's not, e.g., okay to just return the index of the first maximal value?)

Comment: @smarx Yes, exactly. If I always returned the first one, class1 would be overrepresented in my results. (I'm implementing a KNN algorithm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `random.choice` with a list comprehension as follows

```
indices = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(values) if val == largest]
random.choice(indices)
```

As an example, here is the result of calling it a few times

```
>>> import random
>>> values = [5, 2, 5, 3, 1]
>>> largest = max(values)
>>> indices = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(values) if val == largest]
>>> random.choice(indices)
2
>>> random.choice(indices)
0
>>> random.choice(indices)
2
```

Comment: This is nice and short, but it's a bit inefficient if the `list` is long. (It looks at all the values once to determine the maximum and then looks at them all again to find the matching indexes.) Just an FYI, not necessarily a criticism.

Comment: @smarx From a computational complexity point of view it is *inefficient*, however, since `max` runs at C speed, the overhead would negligible for small to medium sized lists and is bound to be faster than taking the maximum with a *for* loop.

Comment: In my case it shouldnt be much of a problem since the maximum size is 10 :D

Answer (score 4):

There are probably better solutions, but here's a fairly "by hand" approach that should be easy to understand:

```
import random

def get_random_max(classes):
    maximum_indexes = []
    maximum_value = None

    for i, n in enumerate(classes):
        if maximum_value is None or n > maximum_value:
            maximum_value = n
            maximum_indexes = [i + 1]
        elif n == maximum_value:
            maximum_indexes.append(i + 1)

    return random.choice(maximum_indexes)

print(get_random_max([5, 2, 5]))  # prints 1 or 3 with equal probability
```